# Run a specific command from a directory

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a bash script where I need to run an init utility within a directory with a configuration file defined. I don't think it's possible to explicitly tell the utility to run the file as an argument, so what I need to do is go to the directory with the config file, and then run the command. I have some logic in place, but its not working -- the utility never runs. Is there any way I can tell the script to go to this directory, and then run the script?

```
cd /var/www/testing-dev.example.co
eval "standardprofile"
```

Comment: Could you be more clear?  You could specify the config file in the bash script and just execute the bash instead.  What does it need to pull from the config, etc. would help.  And yes, you can run the file as an argument - the question is what pieces need to come from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subshell (sub-process?).

```
( cd /the/best/dir/in/the/universe; /path/to/util < /util/config.ini )
```

e.g.

```
$ pwd
/home/jaroslav

$ (cd /cygdrive/c/tmp/;  pwd)
/cygdrive/c/tmp
```